# String manipulation: Save CSV column in variable and remove last character of every item

Tags: string, powershell, csv

I'm trying to parse a big syslog file (from a Postfix/Proxmox server) and... I hate parsing info.

So, long store short: I need to have some info from the file (the proxmox id, the postfix id and other variables). The way I found out to do it its the following:

```
$PostfixCadenaRelay = Select-String -Path 'C:\Makros\InformesMTT\syslog' -SimpleMatch "relay=127.0.0.1" -AllMatches | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delim " " -Header "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"
$IdPostfix = $PostfixCadenaRelay | Select-Object "6"
```

This converts this (a few example lines):

```
Apr 13 13:15:44 proxmox postfix/qmgr[12351]: B444212A67F: removed
Apr 13 13:15:45 proxmox proxprox[13106]: 12A6835AD0D7AFC5728: SA score=7/5 time=1.227 bayes=undefined autolearn=no autolearn_force=no hits=DYN_RDNS_AND_INLINE_IMAGE,HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS,HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR,HTML_MESSAGE,HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG,MIME_HTML_ONLY,RDNS_DYNAMIC,SPF_PASS,T_RP_MATCHES_RCVD,URIBL_GREY
Apr 13 13:15:45 proxmox proxprox[13106]: 12A6835AD0D7AFC5728: moved mail for <cosoriov@mtt.gob.cl> to spam quarantine - 1832996F5AD0D7B11B6FD
Apr 13 13:15:45 proxmox proxprox[13106]: 12A6835AD0D7AFC5728: processing time: 1.309 seconds (1.227, 0.046, 0)
Apr 13 13:15:45 proxmox postfix/lmtp[12863]: 329C512A680: to=<cosoriov@mtt.gob.cl>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=2.1, delays=0.79/0/0.04/1.3, dsn=2.5.0, status=sent (250 2.5.0 OK (12A6835AD0D7AFC5728))
Apr 13 13:15:45 proxmox postfix/qmgr[12351]: 329C512A680: removed
```

Into this:

```
6           
-           
2B70912A69B:
2145712A684:
81CA112A684:
1DA3312A689:
3C6C312A689:
CF37312A696:
722F712A669:
90E6512A66C:
9F6B312A668:
```

Now, I want to remove every ":" from the lines and save that to a variable/file, but I havent been able to.

Using foreach and -replace didnt work, also tried

```
$IdPostfix -replace '\:$',''
```

Also tried using

| ConvertFrom-Csv -Delim ":"

But gives weird text.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove the colon from the end of the string.

```
$IdPostfix = $PostfixCadenaRelay | ForEach-Object { ($_.6).TrimEnd(':') }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but I want to understand that. The ForEach-Object part seems clear. The $_ now I know its the current "object" passed from the pipe. The TrimEnd(':') also know what does. But the whole ($_.6) dont get it. Its because previously it selected the "6" object?. Thanks!

Comment: The `6` after `$_.` is selecting the specific property of the object. In this case column 6.